# Tools for analyzing C++ codebase

Tags: c++, code-analysis, static-analysis

Which tools  would be most useful for analyzing a C++ codebase?
What do they cost?
Can we manage with free and trial software, or are there commercial software that is good and that we really should to pay for?

The main object would be to get an understanding of quality - memory issues etc, also to understand the code (For spotting architectural problems for example), perhaps coding standards.

Primarily statical analysis, but we are hoping to be able to run the code.
Think it needs to be "robust in the sense that it should work with code for arcane compilers.

Comment: What about good old Boundschecker and Purify?  Are they stil the leading apps?

Comment: Its odd that you ask for static analysis and then offer up dynamic analysis tools as examples.

Comment: Boundschecker also have static capabilities, I think.  Anyway, I think it is best to do it dynamically, but I don't know if we will get that far.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The best free tool is your compiler's warning errors, I always use them at maximum level.  The first goal should be a clean build without any cheating (eg. disabling or casting away not-understood warnings).

Visual C++ has built in [Code Analysis](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d3bbz7tz%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) which is good for catching some bugs and Win32 API misuse, but it's not included in the free version and is (obviously) Windows-specific.  This used to be an internal Microsoft tool called Prefast - analogous to FxCop in .Net.

[PC-Lint](http://www.gimpel.com/html/pcl.htm) is good, but verbose and not free.  If you can get a config file to trap 'useful things' and ignore the noise, that would be a big plus.  Again this is for Windows, but I know there are versions for other platforms.

Comment: It's only in the super-expensive team version though, right?

Comment: @Noah - for VS2010 it's in Premium and Ultimate.  For VS2008, Team System and Team Suite.  For 2005, Team Edition for Software Developers.  Broadly: yes, it's only in the more pricey versions, with VS2010 being a little less exorbitant if you want this.

Comment: That's right, the versions all changed with the new release.  I lose track.  +1 for compiler warnings, but I'd add the, "Make it compile without any," rule.  It can be tough, especially if you're using boost, but it's much more apparent that there's an issue if you don't already have 5000 warnings yelling at you.

Comment: @Noah - I would say yes to that except that Visual Studio in earlier incarnations (2005 iirc) puts out some utter trash re STL containers at /W4, meaning projects I've worked on disable certain warnings, not fix them.  Philosophically I agree 100% though - clean builds or bust.

Comment: Would these Visual Studio tools be in trail versions?  How well would it work on non VC++ code?

Comment: @Olav - could be hard to use with non-Windows code, main question is the portability of the target source code. I don't think they ever give these way, but trial versions would have them I would have thought, or you would not be able to evaluate the IDE properly.

Comment: It still does.  Truncated name warnings are one.  The whole, "failed to create copy or assignment operator," when neither is used...  The deprecation warnings.  Yes, you have to disable some useless warnings and use `#pragma warning` in some places, but it's better than the alternative.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at:

http://www.cppdepend.com/

and a good many others:

http://www.chris-lott.org/resources/cmetrics/

http://www.locmetrics.com/alternatives.html

Answer (score 2):

I've heard very good things about [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/). "automatically detect many memory management and threading bugs, and profile your programs in detail"

Comment: A good suggestion, but Valgrind does not do static analysis: you need to execute the code (and ideally to execute it with appropriate coverage) to take advantage of Valgrind.

Answer (score 2):

The number one stink in programs is  [code duplication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duplicate_code). 
You can use clone detectors to find duplicates.  Many clone detectors compare just text lines for exact matches; other compare token streams and will find almost-exact matches where the differences are just changed identifiers.  You can use our [CloneDR](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/Clone) to find duplication in which arbitrary langauge structures are inserted or removed, using the langauge grammar as a guide.  CloneDR works for large C++ systems, as well as many other languages.  At the link you can find typical clone detection reports.

A popular broad-spectrum static checker is [PCLint](http://www.gimpel.com/html/pcl.htm).  This checks for a variety of common coding errors predefined by the tool.  I don't know how well it handles "arcane" (compilers) dialects of C++.

If you want to define custom checks, you need a [full C++ front end parser](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/FrontEnds/CppFrontEnd.html) and the ability to configure your checks arbitrarily.  Our [DMS Software Reengineering Toolkit](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/DMS/DMSToolkit.html) is an engine that can be configured to accomplish this.  DMS's C++ front end can be configured to handle "arcane" C++ dialects, but already covers ANSI, GCC3 and GCC4, MS Visual Studio 7 and 2005. Because DMS is a program transformation engine, it can even be used to "improve" the code quality by replacing poor constructs with better ones.

While not static analysis, [test coverage](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_coverage) tools for measuring how well you've tested your code are very helpful in assessing your code quality.   Just because all your tests pass, doesn't mean you've tested well; unexercised code arguably can have any/all variety of problems.

Answer (score 0):

Theres CCCC: http://cccc.sourceforge.net/ -- result of a research project on metrics.

To tell the truth, I've not found much benefit in such things.  What do you hope to get?

Answer (score 0):

You could try out [Vigilant Sentry](http://vigilantsw.com/), which analyzes C and C++ and looks for advanced errors in your software. This includes memory or resources leaks, and crash causing memory corruption, among other things.

The small business edition is currently only $795 (by far the cheapest on the market for the value) and the enterprise is $4995. Good luck finding what you need.